# Get all the WORDS except one specific word

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get all the words, except one, from a string using JS regex match function. For example, for a string `testhello123worldtestWTF`, excluding the word `test`, the result would be `helloworldWTF`.

I realize that I have to do it using look-ahead functions, but I can't figiure out how exactly. I came up with the following regex `(?!test)[a-zA-Z]+(?=.*test)`, however, it work only partially.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: So I noticed your question is strange. You said you want to check for 'test' but in your results you also stripped out the 123 along with the test. Was that a typo?

Comment: By "word" he meant `[a-zA-Z]+`, without digits.

Comment: Please fix your question to be in line with what you have said in comments (like, you want to do a REPLACE, and exactly what the string should look like before and after the replacement).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I would try to replace the incriminated word with an empty string, no?

Answer (score 0):

Lookarounds seem to be an overkill for it, you can just replace the `test` with nothing:

```
var str = 'testhello123worldtestWTF';
var res = str.replace(/test/g, '');
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to change all found word-occurrences to `word`.  So I need to keep the word test in its place. For `testhello123worldtestWTF` my desired end result would be ['test', 'word', 'word', 'test', 'word']

Answer (score 0):

Plugging this into your refiddle produces the results you're looking for:

```
/(test)/g
```

It matches all occurrences of the word "test" without picking up unwanted words/letters. You can set this to whatever variable you need to hold these.

Answer (score 0):

**WORDS OF CAUTION**

Seeing that you have no set delimiters in your inputted string, I must say that you cannot reliably exclude a specific word - to a certain extent.

For example, if you want to exclude `test`, this might create a problem if the input was `protester` or `rotatestreet`. You don't have clear demarcations of what a word is, thus leading you to exclude test when you might not have meant to.

On the other hand, if you just want to ignore the string `test` regardless, just replace `test` with an empty string and you are good to go.